# Database Connection Error while deploying on Glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb, derby

Hello I am trying to deploy the firstcup-war web application from the Java EE 7 firstcup tuttorial

(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/doc/web-application.htm#GLCFC)

using Netbeans 7.4 with java ee 7 sdk and glassfish 4

but I am getting the following error:

SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [firstcup-war] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002](Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0

Could someone please help, I am completly new to this?
Thank you very much

Comment: In netbeans goto the 'services' tab and make sure, that derby is running. It generally says: 'Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect'. So there are several reasons, some weird firewall preferences on localhost?

Comment: @DoeJohnson Hi and thank you for your answer, it seems to be a security feature in version 7.51, i resolved following this steps:  
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154400/unable-to-start-derby-database-from-netbeans-7-4/21252979#21252979"