# Couldn't Start the Java DB server giving Exception

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, glassfish, javadb

I have Netbeans 7.4 I get the below error when I try to start Java DB or derby connection from Netbeans on windows 7 64 bit. I have Glassfish server installed by Netbeans itself. Glassfish working fine but Java Db isn't starting what's the problem. Please help me.

```
Wed Mar 12 13:55:07 IST 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Wed Mar 12 13:55:08 IST 2014 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1134)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154400/unable-to-start-derby-database-from-netbeans-7-4

Answer (score 0):

**This issue comes when you have wrong credentials while connecting to any DB server, very the user name and password of db which you are trying to connect.**

Comment: i didn't give any username and password yet i'm just trying to connect it with Glassfish simply what's the problem. Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6438

The direct cause is a tightening of the default permissions in Java 7 u51, as described
here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html