# An error when I try to connect MyEclipse with database

Tags: java, database

Today I try to connect MyEclipse with MySQL. But it just doesn't work. The IDE tells me that "There is something wrong of my localhost server of the  port 1527". How should I do to cope with it, and here's the information :

> Sun Jun 12 14:49:03 CST 2016 : access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
>     at
>   java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
>     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1131)
>     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)   at
>   javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown
>   Source)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154400/unable-to-start-derby-database-from-netbeans-7-4

Comment: The stack trace shows that you seem to be trying to start a Derby database server. Not to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: Also, check the connection to your database from a database IDE to verify your connectString/TNS/URL is working. Did you successfully connected from MyEclipse to another database?